# 404 error on Flask app running under gunicorn – is my nginx config right?

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a couple of Flask apps using Gunicorn on a Ubuntu server (with nginx). One of them is working, but the new one I'm trying to add responds with a 404 when I try to hit it.

Here's my gunicorn config (this is being run by `supervisor`):

```
NAME="leaving_app" # Name of the application
NUM_WORKERS=3 # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd /var/www/mattandrews/leaving/
source /var/www/mattandrews/leaving/ve/bin/activate

exec /var/www/mattandrews/leaving/ve/bin/gunicorn leaving:app  \
  --bind my.server.ip.here:8003
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --log-level=debug \
```

If I go directly to `my.server.ip.here:8003` I can see it running properly. This is the `nginx` config:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    root            /var/www/mattandrews;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /leaving {
        proxy_pass http://my.server.ip.here:8003;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /leaving;
    }

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://my.server.ip.here:8002;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

The app running on port `8002` is running on the root (and works), but when I try to hit `mydomain.com/leaving` I get a 404.

Looking at the `nginx` error log, I see these messages:

```
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/leaving/"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 post event 097AA498
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 post event 097CD160
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 delete posted event 097CD160
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http upstream request: "/leaving/?"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http upstream dummy handler
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 delete posted event 097AA498
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http upstream request: "/leaving/?"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http upstream process header
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 malloc: 097F6CA0:131072
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 recv: fd:9 153 of 131072
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy status 404 "404 NOT FOUND"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy header: "Server: gunicorn/19.3.0"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy header: "Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 22:32:25 GMT"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 233"
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 http proxy header done
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 xslt filter header
2015/04/21 18:32:25 [debug] 25809#0: *749454 HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
```

A bit of googling suggests that `11: Resource temporarily unavailable` is related to some [gunicorn issue](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/514) but nothing there worked for me.

Does anyone have any pointers about what to try next?

EDIT: Here's the relevant part of the Flask app:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`? Chances are you don't have a pattern in your urls.py for `/leaving`.

Comment: The app's so simple (two views) it doesn't have a `urls.py`, but I've updated my question with what's in the main Flask file.

Comment: ... so yep @BurhanKhalid, it doesn't cover `/leaving` – but there's also a route for `/who` which doesn't work on either `mydomain.com/leaving/who` or just `mydomain.com/who`. 

I did try changing the `@app.route('/')` to be `/leaving` instead, to no effect.

Comment: Did you look at the gunicorn logs for your two Flask apps? There you can see which one is getting the request and what URL the app is receiving that ends in a 404.